# how to access the solr url outside the server?

Tags: solr

```
     we are using solr version 6.5.1 ,we are set the solr in server need to access the url  outside server ,we using server windows server 2012 now local host weare using this url how to access this url in outside
```

http://localhost:8983/solr/kmartdev/select?&indent=on&defType=dismax&q=amul&qf=name+model&wt=json

Comment: Vidya, Welcome to SO. Please be clearer in requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer, actually we need to open a port into our server. So, I've opened a post from control panel-> windows firewall-> inbound rules. And I've opened same port into azure server also. Now I can access my solr from anywhere.

Hope this answer will help someone and save their time. :)

Answer (score 2):

## When using in same network

When client is in same network, then you don't need to have a public IP of the server to access it. Follow these steps:

1. Find the IP of the server
2. Add into host file of the client, say `XX.XX.XX.XX solr.com`
3. Open `http://solr.com:8983/solr/` for admin panel.
4. Step 2 is not mandatory, but if you dont add in host, then use IP address in browser. It will be `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8983/solr/

## When using in different network

To access the server that is not in your domain, you need to have a public IP. If you have taken the domain name then use `http://yourdomain.com:8983/solr/`, but if not, then add in host, or directly use IP address (steps are same as in the previous ones)

Comment: that is good answer according to the question asked, but can you please let me know, how can I run the yourdomain.com with solr without writing the port?

Comment: @Birendra: you can't. Default port for http is 80. So when you write http://yourdomain.com/, you're saying http://yourdomain.com:80/. If port is anything other than 80, you need to specify as http://yourdomain.com:port/. Default for https is 443, so if you're using https version, you need not to mention 443.

Comment: Kamal Nayan I want the 8443 port with https, can we?